# Want to find out total number of results returning from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how many results have been fetched from mysql through my query...

Answer (score 5):

This is done by calling [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) on a mysql result resource:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users");
print mysql_num_rows($result) . " records";
```

Comment: Damn. Go to sleep, this was mine!

Comment: It's all good. I'm awake programming ColdFusion. *shudder* Anyhow, added links to the docs, hope you don't mind. :)